# I want to do animation in android with alternate time period.

Tags: java, android, android-animation, timertask

For example: The view will animate, it will wait for 4 seconds as it is, again it will animate and it will wait for 2 seconds and then again 4 and 2 secs continously. I tried using scheduleAtFixedRate method from Timer class. Its working for any one time interval, how do I make it work for 4 and 2 seconds continously. Thanks

Comment: Always make it 2 secs, and store a boolean value that you can toggle, and sleep the thread for another 2 seconds when it is true?

Comment: You can achieve that using the Random class

Answer (score 0):

Alternating the start offset can be achieved by using an animation listener, changing its offset on animation end, and restarting the animation.

```
    Animation a = //initialize here
    a.setStartOffset(2000);
    a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            a.setStartOffset(a.getStartOffset() == 2000 ? 4000 : 2000);
            a.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    a.start();
```